How do I get user email and name changes in google workspace report api?
I am trying to get the audit log of changes to user email addresses and names in Google Workspace.
No matter which eventName I choose, I receive an error like Invalid request: Event UPDATE_USER not found in manifest.
The basics of the python code:
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES).with_subject(DELEGATED_ADMIN_EMAIL)
service = build('admin', 'reports_v1', credentials=credentials)

request = service.activities().list(
        userKey='all',
        applicationName='admin',
         eventName=event_name, 
        startTime=start_time,
        endTime=end_time
    )

while request is not None:
        response = request.execute()
        logs.extend(response.get('items', []))
        request = service.activities().list_next(request, response)

eventName has been CHANGE_NAME, CHANGE_EMAIL, UPDATE_USER.
I can't sort out which eventName I need to pull a list of changes that have happened.
The Google domain is in one of the highest tiers of Google Workspace Enterprise. So I'm sure it is not because their tier is too low.

I think the issue lies in the granularity of the Reports API.
While this approach provides a lot of data, it's not designed to capture specific changes like user email or name modifications at the level of detail that you require.
So instead of this approach, to more accurately track user email and name changes, you can try using the Google Workspace Directory API (GWD). With this API can directly access the user information, including email, name, and other attributes.
So what you can try is to follow these steps:

Authenticate using service account credentials with appropriate scope.
Retrieve the List of Users
Store User Information
And Finally Periodically Fetch and Compare

A simple python script to do that would look something like this:
import time
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from google.auth.exceptions import RefreshError
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

# Configuration
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'path/to/your/service_account.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly']
DOMAIN = 'your_domain.com'
SUBJECT = 'admin@your_domain.com'  # Admin email for domain-wide delegation
DB_FILE = 'user_data.db'

def get_service():
    creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    delegated_creds = creds.with_subject(SUBJECT)
    return build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=delegated_creds)

def initialize_db():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_FILE)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
                 (email TEXT PRIMARY KEY, full_name TEXT, last_updated TEXT)''')
    conn.commit()
    return conn

def get_users(service, page_token=None):
    try:
        results = service.users().list(domain=DOMAIN, pageToken=page_token,
                                       projection='full').execute()
        return results.get('users', []), results.get('nextPageToken')
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
        return [], None

def update_user_data(conn, email, full_name):
    c = conn.cursor()
    current_time = datetime.now().isoformat()
    c.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO users (email, full_name, last_updated)
                 VALUES (?, ?, ?)''', (email, full_name, current_time))
    conn.commit()

def check_for_changes(conn, email, full_name):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT full_name FROM users WHERE email = ?', (email,))
    result = c.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        print(f'New user added: {email} - {full_name}')
        return True
    elif result[0] != full_name:
        print(f'Name changed for {email}: {result[0]} -> {full_name}')
        return True
    return False

def main():
    service = get_service()
    conn = initialize_db()
    page_token = None

    while True:
        users, page_token = get_users(service, page_token)
        for user in users:
            email = user['primaryEmail']
            full_name = user['name']['fullName']
            if check_for_changes(conn, email, full_name):
                update_user_data(conn, email, full_name)

        if not page_token:
            break

    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            main()
            print("Sleeping for 1 hour...")
            time.sleep(3600)  # Run every hour
        except RefreshError:
            print("Token refresh error. Check your credentials.")
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
            time.sleep(300)  # Wait 5 minutes before retrying

You can update the waiting times according to your specific needs.
A general overview of the code would be:

Firstly, I'm using the GWD API to directly fetch user data.
Then we are using SQLite to store user data locally.
For large number of users I've handled the pagination to ensure all users are processed.
I've also included basic error handling for API errors and unexpected exceptions.
And finally it runs continuously and detect any changes (after time intervals) due to the nature of the script.

I don't think I need to give a deep explanation of the code, but still if it seems that I should, please let me know in the comment and I will update the answer.

Good Luck!

But would this still capture changes that happened in the past? Yes, I need to know when a name or email change happens in the future. But I also need to go back in time and see what happened before this code existed.

Unfortunately, No this will not capture the historical changes, as it was not mentioned in the question. And I don't think Directory API provides a direct method to retrieve historical changes. But I can think of something like comparing data with old backups or something???? (of course it will only work if there are backups...)
Other then that I think "Google Workspace Admin Logs" and enabled "Audit logs" might help you out. try looking into them. But even then I don't think it will be too accurate.
Sorry but that's all I can think of.
Hope you get it to work. Good Luck.

If the answer was somewhat helpful consider upvoting it. thanks!
